# Generate Mail and Open it in Outlook using Perl

Tags: perl, ole

Does anyone know as how can I make a mail in perl using outlook and not send it just open it on the screen at the end of making the mail and let the user verify and send the mail. I am using Win32::OLE for making the mail.

PFB the code I am using:

```
sub Final_Mail_Outlook{

    my($mailTo,$mailFrom,$subject,$body) = (@_);

    my $Outlook = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application') || Win32::OLE->new('Outlook.Application');

    # Create Mail Item
    my $item = $Outlook->CreateItem(0);  # 0 = mail item.

    unless ($item)
    {
        die "Outlook is not running, cannot send mail.\n";
    }

    $item->{'Subject'} = $subject;
    $item->{'To'} = $mailTo;
    $item->{'Body'} = $body;
    $item->{'From'} = $mailFrom;
    my $attach = $item->{'Attachments'};
    my @outputFiles = glob("$OutputPath\\*.*");
    foreach my $file (@outputFiles){
        $attach->add($file);
    }
    $item->Send();
}
```

This sends the mail as I have called Send function, but I want to verify the mail generated. So is there a way to do so???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an answer to it so thought of posting it also so that someone else needing an answer to this can get help. The key is to use the function Display() instead of Send(). PFB the modified code to open the mail and not send it.

```
sub Final_Mail_Outlook{

    my($mailTo,$mailFrom,$subject,$body) = (@_);

    my $Outlook = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application') || Win32::OLE->new('Outlook.Application');

    # Create Mail Item
    my $item = $Outlook->CreateItem(0);  # 0 = mail item.

    unless ($item)
    {
        die "Outlook is not running, cannot send mail.\n";
    }

    $item->{'Subject'} = $subject;
    $item->{'To'} = $mailTo;
    $item->{'Body'} = $body;
    $item->{'From'} = $mailFrom;
    my $attach = $item->{'Attachments'};
    my @outputFiles = glob("$OutputPath\\*.*");
    foreach my $file (@outputFiles){
        $attach->add($file);
    }
    $item->Display();
}
```